# jQuery scroll to element and then click it

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I'm currently trying to make jQuery scroll to an element (in this case an accordion item) and then I want it to be automatically opened (clicked). So far I can successfully scroll to the item via jquery animate, but I can't seem to figure out how to click it AFTER the animate function has completed. This is my code so far:

```
$([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
            scrollTop: $("#"+ articleID +"").offset().top
        }, 800).then(function(){
            $("div[id='"+ articleID +"']").click();
        });
```

Variables are being defined as function arguments, but the rest of the function is not relevant to the issue.

The code above successfully scrolls to the desired element, but won't click it afterwards. Any ideas how to approach this issue?

Comment: RE: your comment "it's clicking twice" - it's clicking twice because you are applying the animation to two elements and the callback is *call[ed] once the animation is complete, called once per matched element.* https://api.jquery.com/animate/ - you should only need to scroll the body or documentElement, not both: https://jsfiddle.net/8ze3prhf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am proposing a workaround.

```
var t = 800;
 $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+ articleID +"").offset().top
    }, t);
 setTimeout(function(){
    $("div[id='" + articleID + "']").click();
 }, t);
```

Comment: Thanks Shivam Sharma, this works as intended.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: While this helped you get over your current scenario, there shouldn't be a need for a "workaround" for something that's built-in and works as designed in the majority of cases.  For any future viewers of this question, the correct solution is detailed in a (now deleted) answer using the .animate *callback*.   If it's not working in OPs case (runs twice) they'll be some other reason for that.   Using a setTimeout is rarely a *good* solution.

Comment: I agree with you @freedomn-m , but I suggested this after the `callback` solution given and the asker was unable to accept/implement that. I also upvoted the second answer provided by @SMAKSS as that's the real solution.

Answer (score 2):

**[`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) is a promise chain**. **Since [`animate()`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) will not return a promise, so it won't work as expected**. If you want to perform an action after a certain animation took place, you should pass the `complete` callback function to it.

So your final code should be something like this:

```
$([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({// The selector should be $(document.documentElement) otherwise it will trigger the click event twice.
  scrollTop: $("#" + articleID + "").offset().top
}, 800, function() {
  $("div[id='" + articleID + "']").click();
});
```

**NOTE:** As @freedomn-m pointed out, there should be only one selector for passing through the `animate()` function. So you should replace `$([document.documentElement, document.body])` with `$(document.documentElement)`.

Comment: Thank you very much @SMAKSS, it does work. However, it seems to click the element twice, which causes a weird visual bug in which the accordion closes and opens twice.

Comment: SMAKSS thank you for your replies. I will use Shivam's workaround answer as it works perfectly as it is.